# How can I get UTC Timezone Offset with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, offset

When I get the timezone offset with: getTimezoneOffset, I get the value like 360, 270, etc. I want to get the UTC (negative or positive) offset like: -6 -5 -2.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have value in minutes. Convert it into hours dividing value by 60

Comment: and the +/- symbol